# How to center floating divs

Tags: html, css, center

I have 3 columns in a row: voting buttons, sharing buttons, and link to comments.

Their widths are mixed. But I have a problem with **horizontally centering** floating elements inside them. Photo:

[image: Problem with centering of floating divs]

As you can see, there is no problem with centering text (last section). But what about the others?
Here is my code:

```css
.object-buttons {
    
    margin: 0 30px;
    height: 28px;
    display: block;
    /*display: table;*/
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: green;
}

.voting-buttons {
    margin: auto; 
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 30%;
}
.sharing-buttons {
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    padding-top:4px; // vertical "centering"
}
.comments-button {
    float: left;
    padding-top:4px; // vertical "centering"
    width: 28%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: bisque;
}
.share-btn, .tweet-btn, {
    float: left;
}
.vote-btn {
    width: 40px;
    height: 28px;
    border: none;
    background-color: Transparent;
    float: left;
}
.vote-count {
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="object-buttons">
    <!-- Głosowanie -->
    <div class="voting-buttons">
        <button class="vote-btn plus"></button>
        <div class="vote-count vmiddle">23</div>
        <button class="vote-btn minus"></button>
    </div>
    <!-- Share, tweet-->
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <div class="sharing-buttons">
        <div class="share-btn">
            <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://xxx/#" data-layout="button_count" data-size="large" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="http://xxx">Udostępnij</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tweet-btn">
            <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a><script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="comments-button">
        <a href="#">Komentarze (<?php echo $this->commentsCount ?>) </a>
    </div>
    <!--komentuj-->
</div>
```

Thanks for help and other suggestions that could be useful.

**SOLUTION:**

Hi, my problem was solved by using flex-boxes instead of "display: block" and "float" properties. I suggest you to use it for these kind of problems because it allows you to center (horizontally and veritcally) all of possible elements. Also, it helps you to define the element's behaviour on smaller devices.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to narrow your code down further, to the bare minimum of whats needed.

Comment: Please add jSFiddle of your code

Comment: can you try dispaly:flex

Comment: You mean display 'flex' on child or parent element?

Comment: text-align: center needed for [fb-share-button or share-btn]

Comment: Sanka, your answer is totally useless at this case. Ravin Singh, thanks I'm reading about flex properties now.

Comment: try margin:auto

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
Change the width as you comfortable,

.object-buttons { margin:auto; width: 500px; }